# Unable to get object model in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access an object model from my controller but I always get undefine.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent">

    <div ng-form="noteForm" ng-controller="NoteCtrl">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Note</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- other text input here -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="{'has-error': noteForm.c_message.$invalid && noteForm.c_message.$touched, 'has-success': !noteForm.c_message.$invalid }">
                    <label class="control-label">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="c_message" ng-model="note.c_message" ng-minlength="10" required></textarea>
                    <span style="color: red" ng-show="noteForm.c_message.$dirty && noteForm.c_message.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="noteForm.c_message.$error.required">Message is required!</span>
                        <span ng-show="noteForm.c_message.$error.minlength">Message is should be less than 10 character!</span>
                    </span>
                    <p class="text-left">Number of characters left: <span ng-bind="word_count()">100</span></p> <!-- counter -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="noteForm.$invalid" ng-click="sendForm()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</script>
```

And here's my JS:

```
sampleApp.controller('NoteCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.sendForm = function () {
        console.log($scope.note); //ajax process
    }

    $scope.word_count = function() {
        return 100 - $scope.note.c_message.length; //return undefined
    }

});
```

Here's my controller for the modal:

```
sampleApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function open(size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent',
            size: size,
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        });

    }

});
```

And there's also an error if I type any character that is not above 10 characters length the counter is not decrementing. It will decrement if I input above 10.

Comment: What type of `script` is this, remove the `script` tags

Comment: I am using a modal in displaying the form that's why I included the script tag

Comment: @Jerielle Tushar is right those script tags look very suspicious. Remove them. Also, note is null because you never create it. Add "$scope.note = {}" to the start of the controller.

Comment: A suggestion to use angular modal with $modal.

Comment: @Jerielle You can always move the template to a new file rather than using a `script type='text/ng-template'`. That being said, this is commonly used, or so I thought. @all comments?

Comment: Ok I already removed the script tag and I moved the ID tag in the div but when I try to open the modal I have this error: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: myModalContent

Comment: Oh. Not move the id to the div, create a new file whose name is the id you gave. `myModalContent.html`

Comment: @Jerielle Maybe try to just change the script tags to div tags and leave them there with the type and id atrributes still included. If that still breaks then I apologise. There must be something in that code that I don't understand.

Comment: So is it advisable in Angular if everytime I have a modal form I need to create a separate template for that?

Comment: @Jerielle No it seems that manu29.d is right. I apologise. Your method is an accepted convention.

Comment: I just followed the instruction in the Angular UI. Can I just call the ID of the modal like in the jquery selector?

Comment: @Jerielle Did my answer fix the first problem? It might be better if you ask about the problem of greater than 10 in a new question but for quick help I think it might have to do with ng-minlength. What happens if you change it to zero?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your "note" model is undefined, because your ng-model directly tries to access a property of it. Add this code to the controller right at the top:

```
$scope.note = {c_message: ""};
```

Comment: If 2-way binding is to be accepted at face-value, this should not be required. Else, I am missing how angular controllers work.

Comment: The code in the question will work if the model being accessed is a direct descendant property of the controller. If the model was $scope.c_message. It will also work just to add "$scope.note = {}". ng-model will not create a hierarchy of objects. At least this is what I have experienced.